# datePicker not hide for resignFirstResponder in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, delegates

I have few textFields and when I touch one of them there should be a datePicker to select the date and selected date should display in that textfield. This function works perfectly, but after user selected the date and tap anywhere that datePicker should hide as the keyboard does. But it is not working in my code. All other keyboards hide as expected.

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
         textField.resignFirstResponder()
       // self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }



    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField){
         if textField == dateOfBirth{
            let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
            textField.inputView = datePicker
            datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "datePickerChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        }
    }

    func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        //    formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
        //  formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        dateOfBirth.text = formatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
       self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dateOfBirth.delegate = self
        firstname.delegate =  self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Also I tried `self.view.endEditing(true)` to hide current keyboard inside `textFieldShouldReturn()` but not worked. When I select a date and tap somewhere else the simulator stop respond. I'm getting target output as:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_test.bController
>   getCalendar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79097b10'

I'm new to iOS developement and couldn't find out the error yet. If you need more information please let me know.  Any help would or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks strange. Try to add your `UIDatePicker` as controller's property instead initializing in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method

Comment: Could you post more of your code?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov I tried but still same

Comment: @ZonilyJame I have added all the code replates to this function here. If you need to know anyhing else please let me know.